# Login using passport with password in related table laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I'm using Vue for frontend and Laravel as a backend services.

In my case I have two tables `contacts` and `contact_has_entities` tables.

My **contacts** table is :

```
contact_id        name         email
```

And **contact_has_entities** table is :

```
id_contact_has_entity      contact_idcontact         password
```

**contact_idcontact** is a foreign key for the **contacts** table.

I'm using **passport** package for authentication. When login request comes then I need to check `email` from **contacts** table and `password` from **contact_has_entities** table.

I used the below function

```
 public function getAuthPassword() { 
    return ContactHasEntity::where('password', $this->password)->first();
 }
```

In my Contact model i have defined relationship like below :

```
public function entity() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ContactHasEntity', 'contact_idcontact', 'contact_id');
}
```

But I'm getting error like

> getAuthPassword does not exist

Is there any way to achieve this or is it not possible with Passport?

Comment: I think the question you trying to phrase, is not actually the issue here, but the method: `getAuthPassword()` . Apparently from which ever file/class you are calling this method, `getAuthPassword()` can't be reached

Comment: @Johhn Im trying to check password in another table. I have no idea how to check password with related table when im using passport...

Comment: @Vincoder : if the relationships are clearly defined on the models then this should be quite straightforward. Could you please provide the relationships from the models between the two and I guess we can help you from the there

Comment: @Johhn I have updated my question.. please check...

Answer (score 0):

With the above relationship defined then below should work:

1. Access the contacts model and query through the relationship the entities model as shown below:

   ```
   Contacts::whereHas('entity', function ($query) { 
       return $query->where('password', $this->password);
   })->first()`;
   ```
2. Or under contacts define a query scope:

   ```
   public function scopeAuthPassword($query, $password)
   {
       return $query->entity()->where('password', $password);
   }
   ```

   //which would translate to this when:

   ```
   Contacts::authPassword($request->password)->first()
   ```

Comment: I want to use it for login purpose like `Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])`.

Answer (score 0):

Below function in my **Contact** model did the work :

```
public function getPasswordAttribute() {
    return $this->entity->getAttribute('password');
}
```

Here i added the function to use password field from **ContactHasEntity** model.